# Is it possible to use a variable pipe?

Tags: angular

In my use case I basically have an array of data, and I want to sort it using one of several techniques that the user can select from a drop down.

What i'd like to do, and I'm not sure if it is possible, is to have a single bit of markup rather than a bunch of repetitive *ngIf lines.

Ex.

```
sortPipe: PipeTransform = new TextSortPipePipe();
sortField = 'title';
```

and

```
<app-reportsummary *ngFor="let report of reports | sortPipe: sortField" [report]="report"></app-reportsummary>
```

and

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'textSortPipe'
})
export class TextSortPipePipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(values: any[], textField: string, ascending: boolean = true): any {
    return values.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a === undefined && b === undefined) return 0;
        if (a === undefined) return -1;
        if (b === undefined) return 1;
        return a[textField].toLocaleUpperCase().localeCompare(b[textField].toLocaleUpperCase());
    });
}
```

Obviously 'sortPipe' is not declared module, rather a variable name, so that doesn't work, but you can't do {{sortPipe}} either so I'm wondering if there is some sort of syntax that can accomplish this.

edit: I want to change the value of sortPipe dynamically (or fine another way to accomplish the same thing)

```
textSortPipe: PipeTransform = new TextSortPipePipe();
updateDateSortPipe: PipeTransform; // = new SomeOtherPipe();

sortPipe: PipeTransform = this.textSortPipe;
sortField = 'title';
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?  I attempted to create the pipe.

Comment: Sorry I understood something else. You don't have to declare anything, as long as your pipe is accessible from within your module, you only use it like `| textSortPipe: sortField` instead of `| sortPipe: sortField`

Comment: I want to change the value of sortPipe based on a choice the user makes in the UI to determine how to sort the data.  Maybe there is a better way to do it.  I had an alternative way where i had a single pipe with a property that told it how to sort, but it felt like worse design.  I could also just stack a bunch of *ngIf's with different pipes but that sounds like bad design, too.

Comment: Added an example to the bottom of the post.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you don't need to declare a variable to hold a reference to the pipe. Just use it by its name (`textSortPipe`) in your template. Your variable holding the sort type should be passed into the `transform` method

Comment: It works if a single pipe can do all of the different sorts.  I have that and didn't like the design.  What I was hoping for was a way to dynamically assign the pipe that performs just the single sort of sort I want to do.

Comment: You can always have a property in your component that transparently do the sort behind scenes and keep using only one markup as you want

Comment: You should probably just move this logic to the controller or some kind of shareable service instead putting this into a pipe. It is not recommended to use pipes for sorting, filtering or similar array operations: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Ha.  When the right answer is the one you don't want to hear lol.  I'll have to think about how to do it another way.

Comment: In terms of markup, I don't think it will be too ugly to not use a pipe. You'd till *ngFor over items, they would just be sorted in the controller or an injected service. Usually you'd save the original values to a class property, copy those initial values to a class property representing the sorted values, then use that for the *ngFor. Sort the values from something like the change event of the dropdown with the sorting options. The function in the controller/service that would do the sorting would probably have the signature you shared above even.

Comment: Yeah, thanks got it working.  I was mostly getting concerned with how I would handle it once I get to the point needing to page, but that opens up a whole different box of issues XD.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.